# c++ find and handle each lines is slower than php

Tags: c++, performance

Hello i created a program to handle a config file line by checking each lines and get the config blocks but for first time i made it with php and the speed was amazing. we have some blocks like this

```
Block {
}
```

php program can read each line and detect about **50,000** of this blocks in just **1 second** after that i went to c++ to create my program in c++ but i saw a very very bad problem. my program was too slow (read **50,000** of this blocks in **55 seconds**) while my php codes was exactly the same of c++ codes (in action and activity). php was 55x faster than c++ while the codes are the same.
this is my code in **php**

```
const PATH = "conf.txt";
if(!file_exists(PATH)) die("path_not_found");
if(!is_readable((PATH))) die("path_not_readable");
$Lines = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents(PATH));

class Block
{
    public $Name;
    public $Keys = array();
    public $Blocks = array();
}

function Handle(& $Lines, $Start, & $Return_block, & $End_on)
{
    for ($i = $Start; $i < count($Lines); $i++)
    {
        while (trim($Lines[$i]) != "")
        {
            $Pos1 = strpos($Lines[$i], "{");
            $Pos2 = strpos($Lines[$i], "}");

            if($Pos1 !== false && ($Pos2 === false || $Pos2 > $Pos1)) // Detect { in less position
            {
                $thisBlock = new Block();
                $thisBlock->Name = trim(substr($Lines[$i], 0, $Pos1));
                $Lines[$i] = substr($Lines[$i], $Pos1 + 1);
                Handle($Lines, $i, $thisBlock, $i);
                $Return_block->Blocks[] = $thisBlock;

            }
            else { // Detect } in less position than {
                $Lines[$i] = substr($Lines[$i], $Pos2 + 1);
                $End_on = $i;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

$DefaultBlock = new Block();
Handle($Lines, 0, $DefaultBlock, $NullValue);
$OutsideKeys = $DefaultBlock->Keys;
$Blocks = $DefaultBlock->Blocks;
echo "Found (".count($OutsideKeys).") keys and (".count($Blocks).") blocks.<br><br>";
```

and this is my code in `C++`

```
string Trim(string & s)
{
    auto wsfront = std::find_if_not(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int c) {return std::isspace(c); });
    auto wsback = std::find_if_not(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](int c) {return std::isspace(c); }).base();
    return (wsback <= wsfront ? std::string() : std::string(wsfront, wsback));
}

class Block
{
private:
    string Name;
    vector <Block> Blocks;

public:
    void Add(Block & thisBlock) { Blocks.push_back(thisBlock); }
    Block(string Getname = string()) { Name = Getname; }
    int Count() { return Blocks.size(); }
};

void Handle(vector <string> & Lines, size_t Start, Block & Return, size_t & LastPoint, bool CheckEnd = true)
{
    for (size_t i = Start; i < Lines.size(); i++)
    {
        while (Trim(Lines[i]) != "")
        {
            size_t Pos1 = Lines[i].find("{");
            size_t Pos2 = Lines[i].find("}");

            if (Pos1 != string::npos && (Pos2 == string::npos || Pos1 < Pos2)) // Found {
            {
                string Name = Trim(Lines[i].substr(0, Pos1));
                Block newBlock = Block(Name);
                Lines[i] = Lines[i].substr(Pos1 + 1);
                Handle(Lines, i, newBlock, i);
                Return.Add(newBlock);
            }
            else { // Found }

                Lines[i] = Lines[i].substr(Pos2 + 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string Cont;
    ___PATH::GetFileContent("D:\\conf.txt", Cont);

    vector <string> Lines = ___String::StringSplit(Cont, "\r\n");

    Block Return;
    size_t Temp;

    // The problem (low handle speed) start from here not from including or split
    Handle(Lines, 0, Return, Temp);

    cout << "Is(" << Return.Count() << ")" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

as you can see, this codes are exactly the same in action but i don't know why php handling in this code is 55x faster than my c++ codes. you can create a txt file and create about 50,000 of this block's

```
Block {
}
```

and test it yourself. please help me to fix this. i am really confused (same codes but not same performance

```
php = 50,000 blocks and detect in 1 second
c++ = 50,000 blocks and detect in 55 seconds (and maybe more) !
```

i have no problem in my program design. because i got my performance completely on php but my problem is on c++ that is 55x slower than php in same code action !

**i am using (visual studio 2017) to compile this program (c++)**

Comment: i mean the way to reach what i want is the same

Comment: Recommend adding compiler, compiler version, and compiler command line. A [mcve] is also highly recommended.

Comment: added (visual studio 2017)

Comment: What optimization level do you have turned on?

Comment: Does it say debug or release up on top in thew middle?

Comment: Project-><project name> properties->C/C++->Optimization

Comment: Without Optimization, the program will run the slowest, stupidest, easiest to debug way possible. See what happens if you select Release build. That should be good enough for a good comparison.  If still slow, which version of Visual Studio 2017 are you using? Some good code analysis tools in the more expensive packages that will help you find where the program is wasting time.

Comment: `Block newBlock = ...;` - copy, `Lines[i] =...;` - copy. Another copy inside `Add` function. And in a loop! In `Trim` you have two passes over `string` in worse case when it can be done in one. Also you do yet another copy when returning value. Also possibly one more copy since it is not clear (at least for me) if return value optimization fires for `Trim`. The reason PHP is faster is because it avoids many of those copies, working only on pointers. Try compiling with full optimizations. If still slow then you could try *not* using `std::string` since you can't avoid copies with it.

Comment: optimization worked ... realy thx but 80% of my problem fixed ... still c++ work in 6 seconds and php work in 1 second !

Answer (score 0):

First, "code" is singular, not plural.

C++ is a very different language than php.  It is not "the same code", and it is nowhere near the same in action.

For example, these two lines:

```
Block newBlock = Block(Name);
Return.Add(newBlock);
```

First create a `Block` on the stack, and then call `Block`'s copy constructor to make another one inside the `vector`.  You then throw away the stack object.

Also, `vector`s guarantee that they are contiguous, so as you add new `Block`s via your `Add` method, `vector` will occasionally stop, allocate another chunk of memory (twice as big as the last one, iirc), copy everything over to that new chunk, and then free the old one.  Either preallocate the `vector` (via `vector::reserve()`), or consider using something like a `deque` that doesn't guarantee continuity in memory if you don't need that property.

I also don't know what `___String::StringSplit` does, but you are almost certain to have the same `vector` growth problem in reading your file.

Comment: the problem is not adding .... you can remove the vector add and remove the php [] ... no diffrent in speed !!! still php is 55x faster why the way's to reach what i want is the same ,,, you can forget about saving what we found !!! you can delete it ... but still speed is 55x less than php

Comment: Your file reading has the same `vector` growth problem as your block adding.

Comment: about split as i said, i checked and get file content and split in c++ is less than 1 second .... first read file content and split in vector <string> ... it is not problem because happen in less 1 second ... my problem is after this step's

Comment: @MyJustWorking profile your code either manually or using a tool and find where time is spent. We cannot guess.

Comment: dude you think you got your file content and you split the lines ... it is not big deal .. my problem isn't this ! my problem is handling the lines

Answer (score 0):

Culprit is in these 2 lines:

```
   Handle(Lines, i, newBlock, i);
   Return.Add(newBlock);
```

Let's say you have 5 levels of 1 block each. What Happens on bottom one? You copy one instance of block. What happens on level 4? You copy 2 blocks (parent and its child). So for level 5 you make 15 copies - 1+2+3+4+5. Look at this diagram:

```
Handle level1 copies 5 blocks (`Return`->level4->level3->level4->level5)
   Handle level2 copies 4 blocks (`Return`->level3->level4->level5)
       Handle level3 copies 3 blocks (`Return`->level4->level5
           Handle level4 copies 2 blocks (`Return`->level5)
               Handle level5 copies 1 block (`Return`)
```

Formula is:

```
 S = ( N + N^2 ) / 2
```

so for levels 20 you would do 210 copies and so on.

Suggestion is to use move semantics to avoid this copy:

```
// change method Add to this
void Add(Block thisBlock) { Blocks.push_back(std::move(thisBlock)); }

// and change this call
Return.Add( std::move( newBlock ) );
```

Or allocate blocks dynamically using smart pointers

Comment: i didn't got your meaning ... i designed this to get each block inside of other block's .... this is what this program do.

Comment: You recursively call `Handle` and copy all objects in each call, witch multiplies the effect.

Comment: for the starting we need one temp block to get all root block's inside itself... when program start, detect what ever exists inside of one temp block and then check each inside blocks (child blocks) this is not extra effect dude

Comment: I changed my answer so you can understand it.

Comment: now i got it.... but if you see, i used pointer on block so what return is the only our static variable storage .... do you have any edit for my codes about your meaning ?

Comment: You use reference, not pointer. Anyway you make a copy of local variable `newBlock` when you call `Return.Add(newBlock)`

Comment: you are right but as i said before, adding is not my problem .. you can delete the add process and process is just better in mili seconds !!!! it can't change 6 seconds handling (in c++) to 1 second (in php)

Comment: I cannot test it as you do not use standard C++ and I do not have your input data

Comment: i tested it dude ... im sure about that .... i set optimization on my compiler and my problem fixed 80% .... but still c++ is 6 seconds and if i delete the add process, it is still 6 seconds .. you can create a txt file with 50,000 of this blocks and test it your self

Answer (score 0):

Out of simple curiousity, try this `Trim` implementation instead:

```
void _Trim(std::string& result, const std::string& s) {
    const auto* ptr = s.data();
    const auto* left = ptr;
    const auto* end = s.data() + s.size();
    while (ptr < end && std::isspace(*ptr)) {
        ++ptr;
    }
    if (ptr == end) {
        result = "";
        return;
    }
    left = ptr;
    while (end > left && std::isspace(*(end-1))) {
        --end;
    }
    result = std::string(left, end);
}

std::string Trim(const std::string& s) {
    // Not sure if RVO would fire for direct implementation of _Trim here
    std::string result;
    _Trim(result, s);
    return result;
}
```

And another optimization:

```
void Add(Block& thisBlock) {
    Blocks.push_back(std::move(thisBlock));
}
// Don't use thisBlock after call to this function. It is
// far from being pretty but it should avoid *lots* of copies.
```

I wonder if you'll get better result. Pls let me know.

Comment: dude i tested it and nothing changed in speed .... i used this trim and i think there is no diffrent with myself in speed

Comment: @MyJustWorking Weird. Anyway it's quite hard for me to follow what is the input and expected output. If you could add it to your question than I'll try to optimize the code.

Comment: my input is a txt file with 50,000 of this blocks (which i show in the main topic texts) and you can use your own c++ file get content and split functions ( no matter ... they aren't my problem) and test it ... and my output is (waiting 6-8 seconds) to handle this lines and detect the blocks